# Python: Display Ordered Positions

Tags: python

I am trying to display scores from positions 1 to 10 (most wins).
For example:

1. Test1 - 5 wins
2. Test2 - 4 wins
3. Test3 - 2 wins
4. N/A
5. N/A

etc.

I am using a notepad file which stores usernames, scores and passwords (in order), here's the inside look of it (users.txt):

Test1,5,TestPassword$!14

Yes,63,TestPassword$!3

Ok,35,TestPassword$!152

From here on, I figured out how to replace amount of wins with new but now I have to figure out how to display positions of winners and I've been having a difficult time. I could either try to somehow have scores (split by "," and be known as split[1]) be compared then printed out or order the lines in order of most wins from within the notepad.

Things I tried (mostly from other posts to see as a basic format of which would work best):

```
position = 0
choice = input("Want to see the leaderboard (Y/N)?")
if choice == "Y":
   file = open("users.txt","r")
    lines = file.readlines()
    for each in lines:
        position = position + 1
        split = (each.split(","))
        print(str(position)+".\n"+"Username:",split[0]+"\nWins:",split[1])
#not for sorting just printing out in order
```

```
num_list = []
file = open("users.txt","r")
lines = file.readlines()
for each in lines:
    num_list.append(int((each.split(","))[1]))
print(num_list)
print("Max number is -" ,max(num_list))
print("Line number is - ", (num_list.index(max(num_list)))+1)
```

```
num_list = []
file = open("users.txt","r")
lines = file.readlines()
for each in lines:
    num_list.append(int((each.split(","))[1]))
print(num_list)
max1 = num_list[0]
max2 = num_list[1]
max3 = num_list[2]
for num in num_list:
    if num > max1:
        max2 = max1
        max1 = num
    elif num > max2:
        max2 = num
print(max1)
print(max2)
```

```
nums = [1,151,2,53215,31,593,9192,5128,3818,5,38,3]
new_list = set(nums)
for i in range(10):
    high = max(new_list)
    new_list.remove(high)
    print(max(new_list))
```

TL;DR display positions from most wins in order of 1 to 10 from notepad file.

Comment: [sorted](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) may help you

Comment: I'll check it out :)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I would suggest using csv files which are generally more suited for your type of data.

There's a few ways to tackle your problem, the easiest for me is to use pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
# read the data
raw_data = pd.read_csv("users.txt")
# assign column headers for convenience
raw_data.columns = ["user_name", "score", "password"]
# sort by score
sort_by_score = raw_data.sort_values("score",ascending=False)
print(sort_by_score)
```

If you want to use the open function, then I would suggest using [ordered dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001509/how-can-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-key)

Comment: I've been asked to not use modules, but thank you still